# Running raw aggregation JSON string in Spring MongoDB Data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation, raw

I would like to directly send raw JSON strings for aggregations in Java Spring MongoDB Data, in the standard aggregation structure in MongoDB. For example:

```
[
      { $match: { status: "A" } },
      { $group: { _id: "$cust_id", total: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
      { $sort: { total: -1 } }
]
```

Is there something similar to `BasicQuery` for aggregations?

I would like to build an aggregation using the raw string because I want to allow the client to specify the aggregation query.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try using the `MongoRepository` and define a method annotated with `@Aggregation`.

Comment: I think the `MongoRespository` and `@Aggregation` method will create the aggregation in compile time, but I would like to create the aggregation in run time.
Is there something else that can accept any aggregate JSON string and create an aggregate object?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the examples:

```
Aggregation.newAggregation(
    context -> Document.parse("{ $match: { status: \"A\" } }"),
    context -> Document.parse("{ $group: { _id: \"$cust_id\", total: { $sum: \"$amount\" } } }"),
    context -> Document.parse("{ $sort: { total: -1 } }")
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using Spring Data MongoDB's `MongoTemplate` and `Aggregation`. Here is the examples demonstrate the usage patterns for the [MongoDB Aggregation Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples).

In your case, you can write the aggregation code like this:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("status").is("A")),
    group("status")
        .first("cust_id").as("_id")
        .sum("amount").as("total"),
    sort(Direction.DESC, "total")
);

AggregationResults<AggregationResult> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
    aggregation, "your_collection_name", AggregationResult.class);
List<AggregationResult> aggregationResult = results.getMappedResults();
```